# How to apply sidebar template to menu sidebars that are created by the user on a page in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I want to get the same layout as sidebar template for my menu that I have added to my page. Below is the image of the sidebar template.

[image: Sidebar Template]

I want the blue color line effect at the top of the sidebar on my other menu sidebar that I have created. Below is the screenshot of the menu that I have added as a sidebar.

[image: menu as a sidebar]

Can someone tell me how can this be achieved? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can't achieve it with your plugins or your theme then you will have to do it by adding CSS.

To do this you still need a little knowledge in HTML and CSS.

If you want to fix it quickly the simplest way would be:

1. Inspect element (sidebar with blue line) with your browser
2. Find the CSS styles that you need
3. Create a CSS class and add the styles to it (in styles.css or (if your theme has one) in the custom css field)
4. Add this class to the sidebar (with a plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/)